# Razorpay Error: "Amount exceeds maximum amount allowed"

Tags: javascript, jquery, razorpay

I'm encountering an issue with Razorpay where I'm getting the error message "**Amount exceeds maximum amount allowed.**" Strangely, this issue does not occurs with lower amounts. I've double-checked my code and API calls, but I'm unable to resolve the issue. Can someone help me understand what might be causing this error and how to fix it?

Below is my code

```
var options = {
    key: 'API_KEY',
    amount: 51000,
    currency: 'INR',
    name: 'Phone Dekho',
    order_id: data.id,
    handler: function (response) {
        console.log('Payment ID: ' + response.razorpay_payment_id);
        if (response.razorpay_payment_id) {
            var model = {
                orderId: data.id,
                razorpayOrderId: response.razorpay_order_id,
                razorpayPaymentId: response.razorpay_payment_id,
                razorpaySignature: response.razorpay_signature,
                amount: data.amount,
                status: "Success",
                addressId: data.addressId,
                userId: data.userId
            }
            addPayment(model);
        }
    },
    prefill: {
        name: data.fullName,
        email: data.email,
        contact: data.phone
    },
    notes: {
    },
    theme: {
        color: '#F46DBE'
    }
};

var rzp = new Razorpay(options);
rzp.open();
```

I've taken the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

1.Checked the documentation: I reviewed the Razorpay documentation to ensure that I am correctly
implementing the payment flow and setting the amount within the allowed limits.

2.Tested with lower amounts: To verify if the issue is specific to higher amounts, I tested the
integration with lower amounts, it work smoothly with lower amount.

3.Reviewed configuration settings: Verified that the Razorpay configuration, especially the maximum
amount allowed, is correctly set up.

What were you expecting:

I expected the Razorpay integration to process the payment successfully without encountering the "Amount exceeds maximum amount allowed" error. Ideally, the payment process should proceed smoothly, and the handler function should execute as intended, updating the payment status.

Comment: `Strangely, this issue does not occurs with lower amounts` huh? lower amounts are less likely to exceed a maximum allowed amount, so why is it strange that a lower amount works? what amount are you trying? the 51000INR? what amount works?

Comment: it works with upto 30k amount, I'm trying with 30K+ amount

Comment: Have you researched your issue? I did a quick search and found others in the same situation with amounts over 30000 as well - despite the FAQs saying the limit is far higher. Perhaps RazorPay is suffering from bugs - not surprising, considering ...

Comment: I did not found anything on my research that solve my problem, if you found anything then please provide me a source..

Comment: Oh, I didn't find any solution, I found the problem discussed many times over many years, not surprising, considering ...

Comment: Maybe you should contact Razorpay support to ask them about the maximum amounts.